# how can we store information of no.of groups in structure in c language and search for a single group?

Tags: linux

How we can bring out the information of particular group from a structure in C language?

Suppose `group 1, group2 , group 3` are 3 groups and I stored information in these groups.

Now I want to know the information stored in a particular group. How can I get information of that group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct student
{
char name[50];
int roll;
float marks;
} s[3];

int main()
{
int i;

printf("Enter information of students:\n");

// storing information
for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    s[i].roll = i+1;

    printf("\nFor roll number%d,\n",s[i].roll);

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s",s[i].name);

    printf("Enter marks: ");
    scanf("%f",&s[i].marks);

    printf("\n");
}

printf("Displaying Information:\n\n");
// displaying information
for(i=group_number(1 or 2 or3))
{
    printf("\nRoll number: %d\n",i+1);
    printf("Name: ");
    puts(s[i].name);
    printf("Marks: %.1f",s[i].marks);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have any further query